# how to use a string in jsx for the dom part?

Tags: reactjs

When you watch this simple JSX example:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
      </div>
    );
  }
});
React.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

How can I change the "DOM part":

```
  <div className="commentBox">
    Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
  </div>
```

... dynamically based on a variable I submit?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. You use curly brackets:

```
<div className="commentBox">
    {myVariable}
</div>
```

You cannot use arbitrary Javascript there, only expressions are valid.

You can read up on it here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions

Comment: my intention is to store the complete dom part in a database and modify it elsewhere. So including the elements. I basically don't want to hard wire the DOM part in the code.

Comment: I see, you can do it with a rather weird looking syntax. You have to set the property `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` like this: `<div className="commentBox" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: myVarContainingHTML }}/>` - check it out here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#html-entities

Comment: ah thanks! maybe my approach is the wrong way to do it and instead of using JSX I parse a DOM string and directly write React JS code.

Comment: @SebastianKüpers, by "dom string" do you mean html?

Comment: No I think it's fine, but you should be sure that it's cleaned up. If you let users post html you have to be careful about XSS attacks.